# Realizar llamada VoIP en iOS con Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

Estoy intentando realizar llamadas por voz IP en iOS con Swift (usando SpeakerBox de Apple) pero no se donde se añade la red local que yo quiero usar para poder realizar la llamada, el código necesario para realizarlo y la configuración necesaria para el Xcode y que todo vaya correcto.

Os dejo el código donde estoy estancado donde debería añadir el servicio de red.

```
// Trigger the call to be started via the underlying network service

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {

    // Create & configure an instance of SpeakerboxCall, the app's model class representing the new outgoing call.
    let call = SpeakerboxCall(uuid: action.callUUID, isOutgoing: true)
    call.handle = action.handle.value

    /*
     Configure the audio session, but do not start call audio here, since it must be done once
     the audio session has been activated by the system after having its priority elevated.
     */
    configureAudioSession()

    /*
     Set callback blocks for significant events in the call's lifecycle, so that the CXProvider may be updated
     to reflect the updated state.
     */
    call.hasStartedConnectingDidChange = { [weak self] in
        self?.provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: call.uuid, startedConnectingAt: call.connectingDate)
    }
    call.hasConnectedDidChange = { [weak self] in
        self?.provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: call.uuid, connectedAt: call.connectDate)
    }

    // Trigger the call to be started via the underlying network service.
    call.startSpeakerboxCall { success in
        if success {
            // Signal to the system that the action has been successfully performed.
            action.fulfill()

            // Add the new outgoing call to the app's list of calls.
            self.callManager.addCall(call)
        } else {
            // Signal to the system that the action was unable to be performed.
            action.fail()
        }
    }
}

func startSpeakerboxCall(completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)?) {


// Simulate the call starting successfully
    completion?(true)

    /*
     Simulate the "started connecting" and "connected" states using artificial delays, since
     the example app is not backed by a real network service
     */

    print("LLAMANDO....")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 3) {
        self.hasStartedConnecting = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 1.5) {
            self.hasConnected = true
        }
    }
```

}